# How to line drop down menu items horizontally instead of the vertical form

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4

i designed a navbar having some drop down menu items which are all on vertical lines, how do i place them on horizontal line or side by side?? 
The code for my drop down menu....
    
               Log In

```
                  Log In Via:
                  <div class="social-button">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"aria-hidden="true">Facebook</i></a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true">Twitter</i></a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-ins"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true">Instagram</i></a>

                  </div>

              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <div class="social-button d-flex flex-row">
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"aria-hidden="true">Facebook</i></a>
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true">Twitter</i></a>
       <a href="#" class="btn btn-ins"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true">Instagram</i></a>
    </div>
```

If you are using Bootstrap 4

Moreover, have a look to flex, it's really important :) 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/

Comment: Thanks a bunch.it works now, will check up on the flex

Comment: You're welcome, please validate the answer by clicking the green 'V' :)